# Centering a single child div horizontally and vertically on the page

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The child is centering horizontally, but not vertically. I think it is because the example-container needs a height set. What if I want it centered on the entire page?

Please see the below code-snippet

```css
.example-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.example-child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="example-container">
  <div class="example-child">
    <p>Sample Content...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's height will only be as big as the child by default. Add `height: 100vh` or whatever works for your layout.

```css
body { margin: 0; }

.example-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.example-child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="example-container">
  <div class="example-child">
    <p>Sample Content...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Centering a single child div horizontally and vertically on the page

It can be done with less markup and wider browser support by using `transform` instead of `flexbox`

```css
.example-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="example-container">
    <p>Sample Content...</p>
</div>
```